# Can't access getJSONArray in java

Tags: java, android, json

I have this Json from URL:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":
    [
      {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":
          [
            {
              "type":"colliers",
              "thumb":"upload\/estate\/135\/thumb_1. Prologis Park Wroclaw I.jpg",
              "name_pl":"Prologis Park Wroc\u0142aw I",
              "name_en":"Prologis Park Wroc\u0142aw I",
              "completearea":"167 000",
              "completeareaunit":"m2",
              "workingarea":"",
              "workingareaunit":"m2",
              "id_type":"3",
              "id":"135",
              "lon":16.939201369628,
              "lat":51.037378299619,
              "images":["public\/upload\/estate\/135\/1. Prologis Park Wroclaw I.jpg"]
            }
          ],
        "geometry":
          {
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[16.939201369628,51.037378299619]
          },
        "crs":
          {
            "type":"name",
            "properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}
          }
        },

      {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":
          [
            {
              "type":"colliers",
              "thumb":"upload\/estate\/136\/thumb_2. Prologis Park Wroclaw III.jpg",
              "name_pl":"Prologis Park Wroc\u0142aw III",
              "name_en":"Prologis Park Wroclaw III",
              "completearea":"129 500",
              "completeareaunit":"m2",
              "workingarea":"",
              "workingareaunit":"m2",
              "id_type":"3",
              "id":"136",
              "lon":16.928386702881,
              "lat":51.105440250407,
              "images":
                [
                  "public\/upload\/estate\/136\/2. Prologis Park Wroclaw III.jpg"
                ]
            }
          ],
        "geometry":
          {
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[16.928386702881,51.105440250407]
          },
        "crs":
          {
            "type":"name",
            "properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}
          }
        },
        .................... more more more...
```

I need to put my hands on properties in a list.

So it would be features -> properties -> name_en (list of objects like that)

I try this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(Json_str);    
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray jsonFeaturesArr = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("features"));
```

in order to create first Json Array, but I can't even do that. I get error:
The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

(I have the same error for "getJSONObject"). Sth must be missing, I'm a java/android Newbie.

If I solve error how do I go deeper into Json?

Thanx in advance for Help.

Comment: Look at your import statements and verify that you really import `org.json.JSONObject` (and not a class with the same name but from a different package)

Comment: You could use GSON to parse the JSON into Java objects like this: http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Comment: I use: import org.json.simple.JSONObject; I also tried: import org.json.JSONObject; but It still doesnt work.

Comment: It definitly won't work with `org.json.simple.JSONObject` (that class doesn't have te method you're looking for). But it really should work with the other class (`org.json.JSONObject`)

Comment: Nice idea too. I will take a look.

Comment: Yes I see now. They are 2 totaly different things. I removed entire simple Json library from code and it works.

Comment: Its worked for me.. but @baron_bartek .. can i work with two libraries.? i need that sample.json also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try as:

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String str_type=jSONObject.getString("type");

// using JSONArray
JSONArray featuresArr = jSONObject.getJSONArray("features");
  for (int i=0; i<featuresArr.length; i++){
    JSONObject anotherjsonObject = featuresArr.getJSONObject(i);
    //access the fields of that json object
    String str_type_one=anotherjsonObject.getString("type");
   JSONArray featuresArr_properties = anotherjsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");

   JSONObject propertiesjsonObject = featuresArr_properties.getJSONObject(0);
   String str_type=propertiesjsonObject.getString("type");
   String str_type=propertiesjsonObject.getString("thumb");
   String str_type=propertiesjsonObject.getString("name_pl");
   String str_type=propertiesjsonObject.getString("name_en");
 ////parse all items ...........
  }
```

Comment: what does `try as` indicate? can't you specify what is the problem in user's way of doing?

Comment: Big Thanx and +1. I encountered some problems with your code. Below I will give 100% working code.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like XML, but a JSON.

You should initialize a JSONObject with that string.

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

And then to access a certain field just check if it exists, and then try to get a data from that field, for example to get the JSONArray call:

```
if (obj.has("features")&&!obj.isNull("features")){
  JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("");
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    JSONObject anotherObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
    //access the fields of that json object
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh. Sorry! Yes Offcourse its JSON :)

Comment: No. I made Imran's code work (see below). Is your solution better? :) Big thanx for support.

Comment: Its almost the same code, but you need to check if the jsonobject has the key before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Workable code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    try {

        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(Json_str);
        String str_type=jSONObject.getString("type");

        JSONArray featuresArr = jSONObject.getJSONArray("features");
          for (int i=0; i<featuresArr.length(); i++)
          {
            JSONObject anotherjsonObject = featuresArr.getJSONObject(i);
            String str_type_one=anotherjsonObject.getString("type");
           JSONArray featuresArr_properties = anotherjsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");

           JSONObject propertiesjsonObject = featuresArr_properties.getJSONObject(0);
           str_type=propertiesjsonObject.getString("name_pl");
          }         

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Jsor parser error","Oh no!"  + e);
    }
```